# Core Data Relationship sort by child's properties

Tags: ios, core-data

I have two Core Data entities, say a Manager and an Employee. Each Manager has two and only employees. The Employees have a hour integer of when they clock in and when they clock out.
How can I create a Predicate that checks if the managers have employes who clock in before a certain time and clock out after a certain time?

If the relationship was expressed as an array instead of set I could do this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.employees[0] > %i && SELF.employees[1] < %i", clockIn, clockOut];
```

I also could separate the check in time and check out time as two separate entities with the same properties, but this seems to go against the whole concept of OOP.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.employees.in.hour > %i && SELF.employees.out.hour < %i", clockIn, clockOut];
```

I also tried adding a category to Manager that returns the "in", but the I get a **Keypath not found in entity...** error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the aggregate operators `ALL`, `ANY`, `SOME` and `NONE`:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL employees.inTime > %i && ALL employees.outTime < %i", clockIn, clockOut];
```

You haven't said what the inTime and outTime attributes are named so replace as appropriate.